# translating from assembly( x64) to C

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I have a function, which panicked.
The crash shows the below assembly code.
Can anyone please explain how to translate it to C, which will help me to understand the problem.

```
push   %rbp

mov    %rsp,%rbp

sub    $0x40,%rsp

mov    0xbca741(%rip),%rax 

mov    %r15,-0x8(%rbp)

mov    %rbx,-0x28(%rbp)

mov    %rdi,%r15

mov    %r12,-0x20(%rbp)

mov    %r13,-0x18(%rbp)

mov    %r14,-0x10(%rbp)

cmpl   $0x3b,0x4(%rax) --> panicked here.
```

the function is taking only one argument.

Comment: Why don't you post the function which is in C here.

Comment: If you're seeing this in a debugger, then you should also be able to see the call stack so you can find where in your code the crash happens. Also, you *are* debugging your "debug" version of the program, which contains debug information like where to find the sources so you can see the source instead of the assembly?

Comment: What kind of software is this? Some study material or real software? Can you post the complete function, or at least a bit more.

Comment: post your function... Basically you want to convert assembly code to C code. Is it really possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating to C isn't really possible.

But here's what's going on:

1. The line `mov 0xbca741(%rip),%rax` reads a static/global variable into `%rax`.
2. `cmpl $0x3b,0x4(%rax)` treates this value as a pointer, and tries to access offset 4 on it, and compare with 0x3b (decimal 59).
3. The pointer which was read into `%rax` was apparently invalid, so trying to access it caused a crash.

The key question is which global/static variable it was. But this information can't be found without the C source (or disassembly which uses debug information).